# Удалить элемент коллекции во время дебага в intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка

При дебаге в идее есть возможность подменять значения переменных Evaluate -> set value, но могу ли я изменить коллекцию (удалить элемент коллекции)?

Пробовал через remove

`col.remove(col.iterator().next())`

Но что-то не вышло

`Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception.`

Comment: Попробуйте не col.remove, а iterator.remove

Comment: Вы хотите удалить элемент именно во время дебага? И вот это выполняете в консоли дебага?

Comment: нажимаю alt+F8 и туда пишу

Comment: Не выходит, та же ошибка

Comment: ну в принципе можно `col.remove(indexOfElement)` только смотря когда. Если во время цикла - то будет потом все равно ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось вот так сделать, т.е. это возможно впринципе. (С обычным итератором тоже работает).